# rank $k$ implies nonzero minor of size $k \times k$ but for for the vacuous case of $k=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Note 0: I use 'minor' to refer to both sub-matrix and its determinant. So when you delete row k and column $l$, you get a *minor matrix*. Its determinant is a *minor determinant*.

Is this true for $k=0$ instead of $k=1, ..., \min\{m,n\}$?

> Proposition: Let $F$ be a field. For any $A \in F^{m \times n}$ with $1 \le rank(A)=k \le \min\{m,n\}$, we have that some minor determinant $\det(M_{(i,j)})$ of a minor matrix of $M_{(i,j)}$, of size $k \times k$, is nonzero.

I was thinking vacuously yes, but I think it's still no because the empty sum is zero or something (unlike the empty product which is 1). But I think it should be yes because there's no such thing as a $0 \times 0$ matrix...

Note 1: see the comments turned into cw answer

Note 2: I know rank 0 iff the zero matrix. I don't really see how this helps though. My concern is (mainly?) about how you say determinant of nothing is 1 or at least nonzero instead of 0. In this case, refer to Note 1.

Comment: The determinant of an empty matrix is usually defined to be $1$. In view of Leibniz's formula $\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}a_{i\sigma(i)}$, recall that a permutation is a bijective map on a set. Since there is exactly one bijective map (namely, the identity map) on the empty set, the *sum* in Leibniz's formula isn't empty and it contains exactly one summand. However, the *product* $\prod_{i\in\emptyset}a_{i\sigma(i)}$ is empty. Hence $\det(A)=\operatorname{sgn}(\operatorname{id})\times1=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix has rank 0, then it is the zero matrix.

Comment: i know. but anyway my question then is about the 0x0 minors of, well, i guess any matrix and not just the zero matrix. see my edit to OP please.